# Get more recent data Firestore Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on an App of the Social Network type on Android. My project is connected to Firebase. Everything works perfect. But I need that for example, the publications are returned from the most recent to the oldest. I'm using Cloud Firestore.

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
CollectionReference collectionReference = db.collection("eventos");

collectionReference.limit(2).get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot documentSnapshots) {
        datos.removeAll(datos);

        for (DocumentSnapshot document : documentSnapshots.getDocuments()) {
            Map<String, Object> mapaEvento = document.getData();
            vento evento = new Evento((String) mapaEvento.get("usuario"), (String) mapaEvento.get("titulo"), (String) mapaEvento.get("categoria"));
            datos.add(evento);
         }
         adaptadorRecyclerHome.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Comment: In case you did not understand, what I want is to get the data from the most recent to the oldest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How I would do it?

When you insert a `JSON` to firebase, add another field called `timestamp` that has the time of when it was inserted.

Then use [Query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query) to `orderByChild('timestamp')`

```
 Query query = db.child("eventos").orderByChild("timestamp");
```

Comment: This seems like the optimal solution.